# Scroll VIew and MBProgressHUD

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller, hud

I am new to iphone development. What i have done here is, loading a view with a scroll view on which I m showing pictures.
I have got a basic navigation controller in the app..
Now, during the loading of picture if the picture is not fully loaded i want to add a MBProgressHUD.. 
I m using the following code for that but, not able to see the it infront of the scroll view although the hud is added on the view as i am unable to move the scroll View..

```
HUD = [[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.navigationController.view animated:YES] retain];
[[self.view superview] bringSubviewToFront:self.navigationController.view];
```

Any Suggestions please... Thanks for your help..

Comment: Yes the HUd is an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming when you do:

```
HUD = [[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.navigationController.view animated:YES] retain];
```

You get an `UIImageView`, you can do something like:

```
[scrolView.view addSubView HUD.view];
HUD.frame=CGRectMake(x,y,width,height) //So you can specify where you want your image.
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on [RuiAAPeres](https://stackoverflow.com/users/491239/ruiaaperes)'s answer, here's some more complete code in Swift:

```
let frameHeight = self.tableView.frame.size.height
let frameWidth = self.tableView.frame.size.width
let hudHolderYCoord = frameHeight / 4 + self.tableView.contentOffset.y
let hudHolder = HUDHolderView(frame: CGRectMake(0, hudHolderYCoord, frameWidth, frameHeight / 2))
hudHolder.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
self.view.addSubview(hudHolder)
let hud = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(hudHolder, animated:true)
let label = "Just a sec.."
hud.labelText = label
```

Answer (score 0):

Whether its scrollview or tableview, you can refer the following link

[MBProgressHUD at center added to tableView or scrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28622678/how-to-fix-the-position-of-mbprogresshud-to-center-in-a-uitableview/44509820#44509820)