# How to fix the position of MBProgressHUD to center in a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, mbprogresshud, uirefreshcontrol

I have a scenario where I am using third party library [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) on a **UITableViewController** but the issues is whenever I scroll up and down the HUD moves with the scroll.

I don't want to disable the UITableView scroll and also I want to keep the HUD in the centre of the UITableView.

Is there a possible way of implementing it?

Comment: plz send me code you use to add mbprogressHud  in tableview...

Comment: Please provide some code if you have a specific problem like this. Its enough to display the code how you add the `MBProgressHud` to your view, so we know what you are doing and we can help you ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding HUD to the tableview's super view or `navigationController.view` fixes the problem:

```
UIView *view = self.tableView.superview;
// UIView *view = self.navigationController.view; if you are using navigationController
if (view != nil) {
    MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:view animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue may that you are adding the HUD in tablview, so add in your view like..

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeText;
    hud.labelText = @"Loading";
}
```

Comment: yes I am adding the HUD to the TableViewController and I cannot change the implementation of the class. Is there a way of keeping the HUD in center of the tableview, even when I scroll up and down

Answer (score 0):

Create the object of MBProgressHUD(example: MBProgressHUD *HUD). Initialize it and add HUD as subview on your main view and do this

```
[HUD setCenter:self.view.center];
[HUD setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

Comment: @Jasmeent:my main view is TableView which is derived from the ScrollView, whenever I add HUD to table view it scrolls up and down with the table rows. I want to keep it in the center of the table view always

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a possible way to fix. Before `[HUD show:YES]`, add this code.

```
HUD.yOffset = CGRectGetMinY(self.tableView.bounds);
```

and that's it.

It looks like `HUD`'s `view.frame` is set as it's superview's `frame`, and therefore it's on a wrong position if you scroll down and then show `HUD`. Adding the line will add `HUD`'s `yOffset` to the amount of scroll down.

Comment: This will set the initial position of the HUD to be at center of the screen after scrolling. However if you scroll the screen after it appear it doesn't stick at the middle of the screen.

Comment: Yes, I used it with `HUD.userInteractionEnabled = NO;`. Otherwise you should reset its position whenever the view is scrolled by implementing `-(void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`

Comment: Got it, thanks! Btw now I'm using an alternative way, which is to attach the HUD to UITableView's superview, that way the HUD will appear in the middle without setting yOffset and user interaction is disabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me. Set it to the parentViewController, then View.

```
let spinningActivity = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.parentViewController?.view, animated:true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding it to the navigation controller as instructed above and I got some unwrapping errors when I translated it to swift. I found [this fix](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD/issues/165) and it works every time. Credit to Aleksei Kaut :-).

```
- (void)showLoadingIndicator
{
  [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow animated:YES];
}

- (void)hideLoadingIndicator
{
  [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Swift 3.0**

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        progress = MBProgressHUD(view: view) // <<-- That's the trick
        view.addSubview(progress!)
        view.bringSubview(toFront: progress!)
        progress?.show(animated: true)
        progress?.mode = .indeterminate
        progress?.animationType = .fade
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solutions is simple. When you are using a tableView, just attach the MBProgressHUD to UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window

For swift 3.0 :

To show the MBProgressHUD

```
MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: ((UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window)!)!, animated: true)
```

To hide the MBProgressHUD

```
MBProgressHUD.hide(for: ((UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window)!)!, animated: true)
```